# Creating an active record scope to order on Jsonb Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sql-order-by, jsonb

I have a table called sessions with a jsonb attribute called lms_data.
I want to create a scope to order by a specific field in the jsonb column.
The following query runs fine `select * from sessions ORDER BY lms_data->>'startDate' ASC`
However the following scope in the Session model wont execute :

```
  scope :order_by_start_date_asc, -> { order("lms_data->>'startDate' ASC ") }
```

It fails with `Query method called with non-attribute argument(s): "lms_data->>'startDate' ASC "`

How can I create a scope that orders based on a field in a jsonb column ?

Comment: Smells very much like an anti-pattern. If your schema is fixed enough that you can write a scope about it you should use an actual database column that can contain a real date. https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/

Answer (score 6):

As of Rails 6 Raw SQL is disallowed by `order` referring to it as a "dangerous query method"; however the deprecation warning also offered that "Known-safe values can be passed by wrapping them in `Arel.sql()`" so we can work around your error by creating an `Arel::SqlLiteral` like so

```
scope :order_by_start_date_asc, -> { order(Arel.sql("lms_data->>'startDate'").asc) }
```

We could convert the inner string into a node all of its own but this should get you over the hurdle in question.

To convert this to full `Arel` you can use

```
order(
  Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('->>',
    Arel.sql('lms_data'),
    Arel.sql("'start_date'")
).asc)
```